# How to add data into exiting PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell

I created PSCustomObject that collect some data. How can I add more values to it later on?

As exmaple

Code:

```
$numbers += for ($i = 0; $i -lt 2; $i++)
{ 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        SmallNumber = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 10
        BigNumber = Get-Random -Minimum 100 -Maximum 1000
        }
}
```

$numbers contain:

```
SmallNumber BigNumber
----------- ---------
          2       139
          9       544
```

My questions are:

- How to add additional 4 as 'SmallNumber' and 123 as 'BigNumber' to existing object?
- How to add just 5 as 'SmallNumber'.

Sample of what I want to achieve:

```
SmallNumber BigNumber
----------- ---------
          2       139
          9       544
          4       123
          5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set up numbers as below you should be able to just add more PSCustomObject into your object.

See this example:

```
$numbers = @()
$numbers += for ($i = 0; $i -lt 2; $i++)
{ 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        SmallNumber = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 10
        BigNumber = Get-Random -Minimum 100 -Maximum 1000
        }
}

$numbers += [PSCustomObject]@{
    SmallNumber = 4
    BigNumber = 123
}

$numbers += [PSCustomObject]@{
    SmallNumber = 5
}
```

Now `$Numbers` contains:

```
SmallNumber BigNumber
----------- ---------
          3       422
          4       751
          4       123
          5
```

Comment: Beautiful though it took a little time for me to understand.